# sizeof(void) equals 1 in C?

Tags: c, sizeof, void

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the size of void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666224/what-is-the-size-of-void)

Hi all !
I am using gcc for compiling my C programs, just discovered accidentally that the sizeof(void) is 1 byte in C.

Is there any explanation for this ? I always thought it to be ZERO (if it really stores nothing) !

Thanks !

Comment: `void` has no size because `void` is an incomplete type. You cannot take the `sizeof` of an incomplete type.

Comment: If I try to create a SO-question with this title, I soon enough get a lot "related questions" around this very point...

Answer (score 8):

This is a non standard extension of gcc, but has a rationale. When you do pointer arithmetic adding or removing one unit means adding or removing the object pointed to size. Thus defining `sizeof(void)` as 1 helps defining `void*` as a pointer to byte (untyped memory address). Otherwise you would have surprising behaviors using pointer arithmetic like `p+1 == p` when p is `void*`.

The standard way would be to use `char* for that kind of purpose (pointer to byte).

Answer (score 2):

this is a gcc specific feature - see here
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith

or

[What is the size of void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666224/what-is-the-size-of-void)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't ask for `sizeof(void)` since you never use `void` as type. I guess the behavior you are experimenting depends on the specific compiler. On my gcc it returns 1 as well.