# Why crash program by access pointer? In C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, stack

I tried to access a pointer but the program crashes. With memory access error.
I receive the pointer from a stack.  (pop- function). As a void*-pointer. 
**Why an I getting this behavior?**

```
int main()
{
    int MAX = 5;
    int field[MAX];
    int i; /* for the loop */
    int *pInt = NULL;

    initStack();

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        field[i] = i;
        push((field + i));  // HERE CRASH
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        pInt = pop();   /* fetch next integer */

        printf("%d\n", *pInt); /* print value */
    }



    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have tested my stack. And it works. But with for-loops it crashes.

My stack implementation. 
I get the error always I access to the pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "stack.h"

/* 
   actual stack data structure
   This pointer will pointing at the actual field (of void * pointers) 
   that represents the stack.
 */
void **array;

/* the current capacity of the stack */
int max = 10;

/* counter variable for counting the elements of the stack. */
int counter = 0;

/* 
    offset address 
    points at the top element of the stack.
*/
int offset = -1;

void initStack(void)
{

    array = malloc(sizeof(void) * max);
    assert(array); /* tests whether pointer is assigned to memory. */
}

/*
    grow: increases the stack by 10 elements.
          This utility function isn't part of the public interface
*/
void grow(void)
{
    max += 10; /* increases the capacity */

    int i; // for the loop
    void **tmp = malloc(sizeof(void) * max);

    /* copies the elements from the origin array in the new one. */
    for (i = 0; i < max - 10; i++)
    {
        *(tmp + i) = *(array + i);
    }

    array = tmp; /* setups the new one as basis */
}

/* push: pushs the argument onto the stack */
void push(void *object)
{

    assert(object); /* tests whether pointer isn't null */

    if (offset < max)
    {

        offset++; /* increases the element-pointer */

        /* 
            moves pointer by the offset address 
            pushes the object onto stack 
         */
        *(array + offset) = object;
    }
    else /* stack is full */
    {

        /* TODO */
        grow();
        push(object); /* recursive call */
    }
}

/*
    pop: pops the top element of the stack from the stack.
*/
void *pop(void)
{
    printf("\tBEFORE\n"); //DEBUG
    void *top = *(array + offset);
    assert(top);
    assert(array + offset);
    printf("\tAFTER  void *top = *(array + offset);\n"); //DEBUG
    // int *pInt = top;
    // printf("\tpop: value= %d\n", *top); /* DEBUG */

    /* decreases the offset address for pointing of
        the new top element */
    offset--;

    return top;
}
```

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: `(int *)pop()` this address must be invalid. [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: @ChristianBender  It is unclear how field is declared and defined.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have removed  (int *) but still error.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow sorry. I have updated my comment.

Comment: @ChristianBender  This statement     array = malloc(sizeof(void) * max); does not make sense because the type void is incomplete and the sizeof( void ) is undefined or some compilers make it equal to 1.

Comment: so many malloc and never free, this is leaking lot of memory, realloc can simplify your code

Comment: sizeof(void) is never a good decision.

Comment: `sizeof(void)` is not only not a good decision, it is a *constraint violation*: "The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has [...] an incomplete type" ([C2011, 6.5.3.4/1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p1)).  As such, conforming compilers are obligated to emit a diagnostic about it.  I find it a bit surprising that GCC (v4.8.5) relegates this particular diagnostic to those that it presents only when its `-pedantic` option is in effect, but in fact it does so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that kind of allocation:

```
void initStack()
{

    array = malloc(sizeof(void) * max);
}
```

`sizeof(void)` is illegal but some compilers [consider it legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350599/sizeofvoid-equals-1-in-c) like `gcc`, which in that case returns `1`, which isn't enough for your `int` pointer.

So you could fix those by passing the size of the element:

```
void initStack(int sz)
{
    array = malloc(sz * max);
```

call by

```
initStack(sizeof(int *));
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in your stack implementation.  In both `initStack` and `grow`, you do this:

```
malloc(sizeof(void) * max);
```

This is invalid, as `void` doesn't have a size, although some compilers will evaluate this to 1.  So you aren't allocating enough space for an array of `void *`.  As a result, you write past the end of allocated memory which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Change the type you're getting the size of to `void *` in both places.

```
malloc(sizeof(void *) * max);
```

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that this sort of mixup can be avoided generically by referring directly to the size of the elements being allocated.  For example, `array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * max)`.  That even continues to work if the type to which `array` points is later changed.

Comment: Whenever you are operating on pointer add Null check always and also push field +i will be invalid index when i value is max -1.for example id you have array [5] valid index will be 0 to 5 now if you are accesing array out of bound program will crash