# Why does sizeof(void) == 1?

Tags: c, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the size of void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666224/what-is-the-size-of-void)

In §6.2.5.19, the prophets let us know that:

> The `void` type comprises an empty set of values

Then why does `sizeof(void)` yield 1, when 0 seems to suffice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666224/what-is-the-size-of-void

Comment: There's a difference between this question and its older duplicate: this one's accepted answer contains actual proof.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sizeof(void)` will not compile on a C compiler.

> **ISO 9899:2011 6.2.5/19**
>
> "The void type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete
> object type that cannot be completed."
>
> **ISO 9899:2011 6.5.3.4/1**
>
> "The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an
> incomplete type"

This is normative text: sizeof(void) is not valid C.

Comment: ...and yet it does compile with gcc, since it's a gcc extension. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith

Comment: I do wonder how this answers the OP's question...

Comment: @Philip Yes indeed, but it will not compile on a conforming implementation of a C compiler.

Comment: @Lundin: Yep. I mentioned it because I accepted your answer (because it contains actual proof) and wanted it to be as complete as possible. I learned about this gcc extension myself only from the other answers 5 minutes ago  ;)

Answer (score 20):

It is a gcc extension: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith

> In GNU C, addition and subtraction operations are supported on pointers to `void` and on pointers to functions. This is done by treating the size of a `void` or of a function as 1.
>
> A consequence of this is that `sizeof` is also allowed on `void` and on function types, and returns 1.
>
> The option `-Wpointer-arith` requests a warning if these extensions are used.

The reason why `void` needs a size to perform such arithmetics is that `ptr - ptr2` does not actually gives you the numeric difference of the addresses but the number of elements the two pointers are apart - and the size of an element pointed to by `void *ptr` is `sizeof(*ptr)` which is `sizeof(void)`.

Comment: If this is an extension, why does `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic` give sizeof(void)==1? -pedantic gives a warning for using sizeof on a void type, but the code compiles and prints 1.

Comment: @Lundin: because you used `-pedantic` and not `-pedantic-errors`

Comment: @Christoph In my opinion, it should be sufficient to set the -std=c99 flag and then it shouldn't even allow the code to compile without errors.

Answer (score 7):

You are probably using gcc, or some other compiler that does this as an extension (in C, sizeof(void) is not valid).

gcc says:

> In GNU C, addition and subtraction operations are supported on pointers
>   to void and on pointers to functions. This is done by treating the
>   size of a void or of a function as 1.
>
> A consequence of this is that sizeof is also allowed on void and on
>   function types, and returns 1.
>
> The option -Wpointer-arith requests a warning if these extensions are
>   used.

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith

Comment: ...and it is invalid because of §6.5.3.4.1: "The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an
incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-field member" and §6.2.5.19: "`void` is an "incomplete type that cannot be completed."