# Getting size of a pointer after memory allocation

Tags: objective-c, malloc, sizeof

I've been reading about sizeof, malloc, and malloc_size, but for some reason I cannot get it to work properly in objective c.

What I'm trying to do is to dynamically allocate memory and then check the size of the pointer.

I tried doing this:

```
void *pointer = malloc( sizeof(void) * 8 );
long test1 = malloc_size(pointer); // Its value is 16
long test2 = sizeof(pointer); // Its value is 8
```

The link below answer exactly the same question but it doesn't work for me.

**EDIT:**
I also tried using

```
char *malloc( sizeof(char) * 8)
```

but it didn't work either.

Comment: `sizeof(void)` doesn't really make sense. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666224/what-is-the-size-of-void

Comment: sizeof(void) is returning the same value as sizeof(char), which is 1. It doesn't generate any compilation errors nor warnings.

Comment: It's compiler-specific behaviour. GCC returns 1, but Visual C++ 2012 returns 0 and gives a compiler warning. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/tf66xte5.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc_size` is returning the correct answer - `malloc` returns a block of at least the size you request, but it may be (a little) larger. This is just a facet of the way dynamic memory is managed, it parallels the way disk files are made up of allocation blocks. A quick test on 64-bit Intel suggests malloc's allocation unit is probably 16 bytes.

Comment: Thank you!! Now I finally understand why doing malloc(n) with n<=16 will assign 16bytes and why malloc(17) will assign 32.

Answer (score 0):

`pointer` is of type of *, so no matter what memory is malloced to `pointer`, `sizeof(pointer)` should be fixed value, it's 4 (32bit sys) or 8 (64bit sys).

Comment: Then how can I get the size of a dynamically allocated pointer?