# Freeing a pointer in a structure referenced by a pointer

Tags: c

I have a pointer to several structures that have been allocated memory via:

```
STRUCTNAME *ptr;
ptr = (STRUCTNAME *)malloc(sizeof(STRUCTNAME)*numberOfStructs);
```

The structures are accessed via a offset like so:

```
(ptr + i)->field;
```

The structures have 2 fields that are character pointers as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    char *first;
    char *second;
}STUCTNAME;
```

These fields are allocated memory as follows:

```
(ptr + i)->first = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer));
```

This appears to work but when I try to free the pointers within the structures I get a segmentation fault 11 when I do this:

```
free((prt + i)->first);
```

Help?

Notes:
buffer is a character array. Offsetting a pointer by a integer should increment the pointer by the size of what it is pointing to times the integer correct?

Here is a link to my full source code. I have not written some of the functions and I am not using the freeAllpointers and printAll yet.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6UPDg-HHAHfdjhUSU95aEVBb0U/edit?usp=sharing

OH! Thanks everyone! Have a happy Thanksgiving! =D (If you're into that kinda stuff)

Comment: First of all, [do not ever. I repeat, **do not ever** cast the return value of `malloc()`!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Comment: But anyway, you are not supposed to free the pointers to the individual members of the array. A pointer is only to be `free()`d when it was `malloc()`ated (or `calloc()`ated or `realloc()`ated), which is only the pointer to the *very first element.*

Comment: How about `ptr[i].first`? Looks much nicer.

Comment: Have the struct pointers been freed before freeing the char pointers? ;)

Comment: @H2CO3: I believe that is the case. The STRUCTNAME* is malloc'ed but also STRUCTNAME::first is malloc'ed, so that pointer needs to be freed as well.

Comment: @XORcist No, that's not the problem, read the question again.

Comment: It's quite possible that some memory corruption elsewhere is confusing things.  Try running your program through `valgrind`.

Comment: `(char *)malloc(strlen(buffer));` is suspicious. Did you copy `buffer` with `strcpy` afterwards ? You're trashing memory if you are- since there's no room for the nul terminator. Use `malloc(strlen(buffer)+1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In case, you don't initialize all those members in that piece of code, you're not showing us:
  Allocate the `struct` storage (`STRUCTNAME*`) with [`calloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc), so that all allocated memory, namely `first`and `second` are zero at the beginning. Passing `NULL` to [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) will result in a no-op. Passing any wild (garbage) pointer to `free()` may cause a segmentation fault.
- To detect a double-free, set `ptr[i].first = NULL;` after `free(ptr[i].first);` as a defensive measure for testing.

> Notes: buffer is a character array. Offsetting a pointer by a integer
>   should increment the pointer by the size of what it is pointing to
>   times the integer correct?

Yes, except for `void*` on those compilers, which don't define `sizeof(void)`, which is defined to have undefined behavior, to a value > 0: [What is the size of void?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1666224/1175253)

**Edit:**

`void makeReviews(FILE *input, REVIEW *rPtr, int numReviews)` <-- This does NOT return the new value of `rPtr`. In `main()`, it will remain `NULL`.
Do something like this:

```
REVIEW* makeReviews(FILE *input, int numReviews);
//...
int main(){
    //...
    rPtr = makeReviews(input,numReviews);
    //...
}
```

or

```
void makeReviews(FILE** input,REVIEW** rPtrPtr,int numReviews){
    REVIEW* rPtr = *rPtrPtr;
    //...
    *rPtrPtr = rPtr;
}
//...
int main(){
    //...
    makeReviews(input,&rPtr,numReviews);
    //...
}
```

---

`fgets(cNumReviews, sizeof(cNumReviews), input);` <-- Perhaps, you could use something like [`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: I believe fgets works fine since when I print the value of the fields inside of makeReviews the output is as expected. I will try doing what you said with the return type of makeReviews. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mac: You're welcome. I suggested  `fscanf()` as a possible shortcut, not as a fix.

Comment: Wow apparently I do not understand passing pointers by reference? That did the trick. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: You're welcome. You cannot pass by reference in C. What you can do is passing a pointer to a pointer (see edit).

Comment: Oh and yes I see what you mean with `fscanf()`. I misunderstood.