# Could a void pointer store a larger array than its dynamically allocated size?

Tags: c

I am still in the learning phase of C and wrote the following function. I was not expecting it to work because the void pointer is only given 2 bytes which is not enough for my 23 byte char array. Though it is stored the char array and could typecaste it to another pointer variable.

```
void main(){
     void *p = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
     p = "Unites State of America";
     printf("%p length -> %ld, sizeof -> %ld\n", p, strlen(p), sizeof(p)/sizeof(p[0]));

     char *pstr = (char*) p;
     printf("%s length -> %ld\n", pstr, strlen(pstr));
}
```

Result:

```
0x55600dccd008 length -> 23, sizeof -> 8
Unites State of America length -> 23
```

How did my void pointer exceed the size I initially requested?

Comment: assigning to a variable of pointer type like this does not change what is stored at the location pointed to, it changes the pointer to point somewhere else - in this case to the string literal.

Comment: ... leaving no pointers to the originally allocated space, which constitutes a "memory leak."

Comment: you do not use the result of `malloc`, if you want to use it do `*p = "...";` ... and appreciate the result

Comment: Also note that you cannot modify the string.

Comment: `sizeof(p)/sizeof(p[0])` is equal to `sizeof(void*)/sizeof(void)` - it just so happens that `gcc` interprets `sizeof(void)` as 1 and not as an error, so this is `sizeof(void*)` which is `8` on your platform. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666224/what-is-the-size-of-void)

Comment: also `sizeof(char)` is useless because by definition it values 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could a void pointer store a larger array than its dynamically allocated size?

Pointers of any pointer type store *addresses*.  Pointers themselves have a size determined by their (pointer) type, like any other object, and it's very common for all pointers provided by a given implementation to have the same size as each other.  If you allocate memory, then the size is a characteristic of the allocated object, not of any pointer to it.

> I was not expecting it to work because the void pointer is only given 2 bytes which is not enough for my 23 byte char array.

Indeed the two bytes you allocated are not enough to accommodate the **24** bytes of your string literal (don't forget to count the string terminator), but

1. That's irrelevant, because you don't attempt to use the allocated space.  Assigning to a pointer changes the value of the pointer itself, not of whatever data, if any, it points to.
2. Even if you were modifying the pointed-to data, via `strcpy()`, for example, C does not guarantee that it would fail.  Instead, such an attempt would produce *undefined behavior*, which could manifest in any way at all that is within the power of the program and C implementation.  Sometimes that even takes the appearance of what the programmer wanted or supposed.

> How did my void pointer exceed the size I initially requested?

It did not.  You allocated two bytes, and recorded a pointer to their location in `p`.  Then, you assigned *the address of* the first character of your string literal to `p`, replacing its previous value.  The contents of the string literal are not copied.  The program no longer having a pointer to the allocated two bytes, it has no way to access them or free them, but deallocating them requires calling `free`, so they remain allocated until the program terminates.  This is called a "memory leak".

I should furthermore point out that there is a special consideration here involving string literals.  These represent *arrays*, and in most contexts where an array-valued expression appears in C source code, the array is converted automatically to a pointer to its first element.  A popular term for that is that arrays *decay* to pointers.  This is why you end up assigning `p` to point to the first character of the array. The same would not apply if you were assigning, say, an `int` or `double` value to `p`, and your compiler indeed ought at least to warn in such cases.

Answer (score 5):

You allocated 2 chars worth of memory, so now there's a small chunk of memory in the heap waiting for data to be stored there. However, you then reassign `p` to point to the string `"Unites State of America"`, which is stored elsewhere. `p = "string"` does not move a string into the memory pointed to by `p`, it makes `p` point to the string.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is not quite correct here. When you do the below two lines, you are actually leaking memory by not using the actually allocated dynamic memory.

```
void *p = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
p = "Unites State of America";
```

Your pointer `p` holds a region in heap to store `2 * sizeof(char)` bytes but, you are actually overwriting that location with a statically allocated string. All your string operations `strlen()`, `sizeof()` are done in this statically allocated string `"Unites State of America"`

You need to use functions like `strncpy()` or equivalent to copy the string characters to the dynamically allocated location. But since you don't have allocated sufficient bytes to hold the large string but only `2 * sizeof(char)` bytes.

Your other pointer assignment isn't quite incorrect, because you have just introduced another pointer to point to the location where the const string pointed by `p` is referring to.

```
char *pstr = (char*) p;
```

So to *summarize* even if you had use the right string copy functions, copying beyond the allocated size, i.e. copying 23 bytes to a 2 byte allocated region, is a memory access violation and could lead to undesirable results.

Comment: @codeforester I don’t mean what you are trying to say. I don’t understand the purpose of  your comment

Comment: I realized my mistake.