# MSVC: why "extern void x;" is "illegal use of type 'void'"?

Tags: c, visual-c++, language-lawyer, declaration, void

Why this code:

```
extern void x;
```

leads to:

```
$ cl t555.c /std:c11 /Za
t555.c(1): error C2182: 'x': illegal use of type 'void'
```

What is illegal here?

UPD. Use case:

```
$ cat t555a.c t555.p.S
#include <stdio.h>

extern void x;

int main(void)
{
    printf("%p\n", &x);
    return 0;
}

       .globl  x
x:
        .space 4

$ gcc t555a.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c && as t555.p.S -o t555.p.o && gcc t555a.o t555.p.o && ./a.exe
t555a.c: In function ‘main’:
t555a.c:7:20: warning: taking address of expression of type ‘void’
    7 |     printf("%p\n", &x);
      |                    ^
0x1004010c0

$ clang t555a.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c && as t555.p.S -o t555.p.o && clang t555a.o t555.p.o && ./a.exe
t555a.c:7:20: warning: ISO C forbids taking the address of an expression of type 'void' [-Wpedantic]
    printf("%p\n", &x);
                   ^~
1 warning generated.
00007FF76E051120
```

Comment: A variable cannot be of type "void". How can the compiler allocate space for something that is not defined?

Comment: I guess the question is why you think that would be valid (with or without the `extern`).

Comment: You can declare pointers to `void`, but not objects that are `void`, because `void` *"is an incomplete object type that cannot be completed"*.

Comment: @littleadv GCC and Clang accept it, even with `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: @littleadv FYI: declaration != definition.

Comment: @user3386109 `extern` doesn't require the type to be complete. So I suppose the question is where the standard would forbid this use.

Comment: @kaylum Re: "with or without the extern": as example says: `extern void x;`.

Comment: @user17732522 Yup, I see what you're saying. That should be plainly stated in the question itself. Although, even if that line is legal, I don't see how it can be of any use, so I don't see that this question has any value.

Comment: @user3386109 Re: "any value": for ex. for people who test compilers.

Comment: @kaylum I see it as "identifier with incomplete type declared with external linkage". I cannot find in the standard why it is invalid / illegal.

Comment: But the identifier must identify something that can be completed (is complete when the program is linked) — and if you could declare an object of type `void`, it could never be completed, so it cannot exist, so you cannot define a reference to it.  And why on earth would you want to define a reference to something that can't exist anyway?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `extern void x;` does not declare an identifier for an object that cannot exist, just for an object that cannot be defined or used in C code. Suppose we are writing some part of an operating system in C, and there is a place we want to inform another part of the system of the address of some special thing, maybe a hardware vector interrupt address, and the memory there should never be modified or called by C code. Then declaring it `extern void` would let us take its address but prevent us from accidentally using it as a `char` or function.

Comment: Standards don't recognize what they consider cannot exist.  However, YMMV.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Any ideas, why gcc, clang, icc, etc. (all with `-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra`) do not diagnose it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Re “And why on earth would you want to define a reference to something that can't exist anyway?”: I have had occasion to create a pointer value that was needed solely for its value, not to refer to an object. The Unix routines that return `(void *) -1` are one example of this. I may have used some solution like taking the address of a `char` defined solely for that purpose, but declaring an `extern void x;` and setting its address via assembly language could have worked as well.

Comment: GCC isn't a standards-compliant compiler, not even when it's told to be one. It allows numerous constructs that the standard doesn't, and doesn't diagnose them all. Adding `-pedantic-errors` to your collection of options doesn't help (sometimes it diagnoses things that other options don't). It's entirely possible that no one ever considered the possibility — it's not obvious that anyone would ever try it, so no effort was expended on spotting it. I think Clang has the right attitude; it's not something that should work and the standard committee never encountered anyone who thought otherwise.

Comment: @EricPostpischil —YMV: your mileage varies.  I disagree, but my mileage varies too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: C 2018 6.7 4 says “All declarations in the same scope that refer to the same object or function shall specify compatible types.” Is there anything that applies to different scopes? What says we cannot declare `extern int x;` in one translation unit and `int x = 0;` in another?

Comment: Unless I'm misreading something, the expectation from the standard and the compilers and linkers is that if you write `extern int x;` in one TU, there will be another TU that provides the equivalent of `int x = 0;` (which might omit the explicit initializer — `int x;` at file scope is a tentative definition until the end of the TU, and it is then converted to a definition).

Comment: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/3953#issuecomment-740227704

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an interesting case. It does not appear to violate any constraints to declare an identifier `x` of type void with external linkage, but it is nearly unusable.

`void` “is an incomplete object type that cannot be completed” (C 2018 6.2.5 19). When an identifier for an object is declared with no linkage, the type must “be complete by the end of its declarator” (6.7 7). But the same is not true for identifiers with external linkage; we can declare `extern int a[]; extern struct foo b;` and define `a` and `b` later, even in another translation unit.

If `x` is not used, I do not see that it violates any constraint. If the program attempted to use it, then 6.9 5 would apply:

> … If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression (other than as part of the operand of a `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator whose result is an integer constant), somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than one.

But we cannot define `x` in C code because it has an incomplete type, and its type cannot be completed. As long as it is not defined, we cannot use `x` in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof` or `_Alignof`, due the above paragraph, and neither can we use it with `sizeof` or `_Alignof`, because those operators require a complete type.

We could imagine that `x` is defined outside of C and linked with this C code. So some assembly module might provide a definition for `x` that is unknown to the C code. Of course, the C code cannot use the value of the object without having a definition for the type. But it could use the address of `x`. For example, it could serve as a sentinel or other token for pointer values. *E.g.*, we could pass a list of lists of pointers to another routine as a list of pointers where the sublists were separated by `&x` and the end of the whole list was marked by a null pointer. (So two sublists (`&a`, `&b`, `&c`) and (`&d`, `&e`, `&f`) would be passed as `(void *[]) { &a, &b, &c, &x, &d, &e, &f, NULL };`.)

However, compiling `printf("%p\n", &x);` with Clang and using `-pedantic` produces the error message “ISO C forbids taking the address of an expression of type 'void'”. The core reason for this appears to be that 6.3.2.1 1 excludes an object of `void` type from being an lvalue:

- An *lvalue* is an expression (with an object type other than `void`) that potentially designates an object;…

and 6.5.3.2 1 requires the operand of unary `&` to be an lvalue:

- The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an object…

This is likely an incompletely designed part of the C standard, as it does not preclude a `const void` from being an lvalue, and Clang compiles `extern const void x; printf("%p\n", &x);` without complaint, but there seems to be no reason for the standard to treat `const void` and `void` differently in this regard.

On the one hand, Microsoft may have concluded there is no way to use this `x` and so are issuing a diagnostic for it as soon as the `extern void x` is found rather than letting an error happen when code attempts to use this `x`. However, while a compiler is free to issue additional diagnostic messages, it ought to accept a conforming program. That is, for a compiler that conforms to the C standard, the diagnostic may be a warning but may not be an error that prevents compilation.

### Supplementary Note

Noting that the constraint for unary `&` allows “the result of a `[]` or unary `*` operator”, I tested this:

```
static void foo(void *p)
{
    printf("%p\n", &*p);
}
```

Here, `*p` by itself is an lvalue of type `void`, and this is allowed for `&` because the constraint specifically allows it, while `&x` would seem to be a very similar expression, taking the address of a `void`, but the constraint does not allow it since `x` is neither an lvalue nor a result of `*`. Curious.

Comment: [§6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2) says: _An identifier declared in different scopes or in the same scope more than once can be made to refer to the same object or function by a process called linkage._  Straining at gnats, you could take the view that since an object of type `void` cannot be completed, it can't refer to any object or function, so declaring it, even with `extern`, is not legal.   But it requires a non-obvious reading of the statement.

Comment: Re: "it could use the address of x": already tried: gcc produces `taking address of expression of type ‘void’`, clang produces `ISO C forbids taking the address of an expression of type 'void'`. Can you comment on that? P.S. I do not see as well that `extern void x;` violates any constraint.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That is essentially the same as the issue I raise in the penultimate paragraph, that `&x` cannot produce the address of an object if there is no object. Except yours applies to `extern void x;` by itself, whereas mine requires `&x`.

Comment: @pmor: The penultimate paragraph speaks to Clang’s grumpiness about this.

Comment: I don't think the penultimate paragraph strains the meaning at all. The first constraint in 6.5.3.2 is *"The operand of the unary & operator shall be [...] an lvalue that designates an object"*

Comment: Both Clang and GCC produce no diagnostics for `extern const void x; const void* p = &x;` under `-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @pmor: Because that code does not violate any rules?

Comment: Indeed, `const void` is (literally) a different type than `void` and C11 6.3.2.1\1 refers only to `void`. Should it be not limited to `void` but also to qualified `void`?

Comment: Re: "It is not a constraint of the & operator": C11, 6.5.3.2p1: "The operand of the unary & operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a [] or unary * operator, or an *lvalue that designates an object*". The `x` of type `void` is not an lvalue.

Comment: @pmor: `void` is “an incomplete object type that cannot be completed” (C 2018 6.2.5 19). The fact it is incomplete does not mean `x` does not designate an object, just that at this point in translation, the size of the object is not known. As noted in the question, there appears to be no prohibition on `extern void x;` in one translation unit and `int x = 3;` in another. Nor does the fact it is incomplete mean we cannot take the address; `extern int a[];` declares an object with incomplete type, but we can use `&a`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The unary & operator requires (among others) an lvalue. The `x` of type `void` is not an lvalue (C11, 6.3.2.1p1; though of type qualified `void` is). Hence, the constraint "shall be ..., or an lvalue ..." is violated. That is why GCC and Clang complain.

Comment: @EricPostpischil 1) I understand that void is "an incomplete object type that cannot be completed". My concert is about lvalues. The `x` of type `void` is not an lvalue, while `x` of type `const void` (for example) is an lvalue. I don't know whether it is intentional or not. 2) Re: "we could imagine that `x` is defined outside of C and linked with this C code": as I understand such scenario is not covered by C standard. Hence, inside C the type of `x` is not completed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Example: we can take an address of object of incomplete type `const void`, but we cannot complete (inside C) such type. Then what is the purpose of allowing to take an address of an object of such type in the first place? Any comments / ideas?

Comment: @pmor: If you can take the address of an object, you can pass it to other software. E.g., you can call a routine written it assembly language and tell it “That chunk of data that I do not understand but that I am supposed to give to you is at address `&x`.”