# What the C standard says about extern const

Tags: c, language-lawyer, standards

Consider the following program

```
extern const int foo;
extern void blah(void);

int toto(void) {
  int x = foo;
  blah();
  int y = foo;
  return x + y;
}
```

`arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -std=c99 -O2 -fno-pic -S extern_const2.c` compiles it to

```
toto:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    movw    r3, #:lower16:foo
    movt    r3, #:upper16:foo
    push    {r4, lr}
    ldr r4, [r3]
    bl  blah
    lsls    r0, r4, #1
    pop {r4, pc}
```

Notice that `foo` is read *once* then shifted left by 1, which means that `gcc` assumes its value to remain constant across the function calls. Similar behavior is observed of `clang`.

I don't see which part of the ISO/IEC 9899:2017 standard clearly discusses this assumption. §6.7.3-12 explains what to assume about a`extern volatile const` variable (its value can be changed by hardware, but not be assigned to by the program), but this does not apply to `extern const`.

§6.7.3-6 states that the program may not assign to a `const` variable. It is not so clear to me that it implies that an external call cannot mutate this variable.

In addition, the meaning of §6.7.3-6 is not so clear to me. It says

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined

However, here in my example I *declared*, not *defined*, `foo` as `const`. The difference between declaration and definition is given in §6.7-5:

> A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers. A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that: — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;

Comment: If you declare it as `extern const int`, then there should be a `cont int` definition of it in one of the source files.

Comment: Would you know where the standard states that if a variable is declared `extern const` in a compilation unit, it must be declared `const` in the unit that defines it?

Comment: I think having mismatching qualifiers between declaration and definition of an object with external linkage is one of those "implicit" undefined behavior things. I don't think the standard explicitly states that the qualifiers must match across translation units. So modifying `foo` in any way (and it isn't declared as `volatile`) would be undefined behavior.

Comment: `I declared, not defined, foo as const. The difference between`  But but but but but you can't declare and define an object with different qualifiers. https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7p4 then https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.7 and https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p10

Comment: Actually you can't redeclare object with different qualifiers, and definition is one form of declaration. The rest is what KamilCuk has said.

Comment: Off topic, but may be useful: [`extern void` vs. `const extern void`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70948856/1778275).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, here in my example I *declared*, not *defined*, `foo` as `const`. The difference between declaration and definition is given in §6.7-5:…

The compiler may assume an object declared as `const` is also defined as `const`, per C 2018 6.2.7 2:

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

and 6.7.3 11:

> For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version of a compatible type; the order of type qualifiers within a list of specifiers or qualifiers does not affect the specified type.

(Note that that sentence does not say what the requirement is for an unqualified type to be compatible with a qualified type, unless we include “no qualifiers” as a qualified type. However, the rules for compatibility are stated throughout the C standard on an affirmative basis: Two types are compatible only if there is a rule stating they are; any types without a statement asserting they are compatible are not compatible.)

> §6.7.3-6 states that the program may not assign to a `const` variable. It is not so clear to me that it implies that an external call cannot mutate this variable.

Per the above, the compiler may assume that `foo` is `const` throughout the program and that nothing in the program changes it. If something outside the program could change it, it should be declared `volatile`.

Comment: Thanks. To summarize, if this `extern` variable can be validly linked, it must have a definition somewhere, and this definition must include the `const` qualifier because declaring and defining the same variable with incompatible quantifiers has undefined behavior, so it would be undefined behavior to attempt writing to it, so it stays constant.

Answer (score 3):

> What the C standard says about extern const

I think I'll throw [6.3.2.1 p1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p1)

> An lvalue is an expression [...] that potentially designates an object. [...] A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue tha [...] does not have a const-qualified type [...]

`foo` is designating an object. `foo` is const-qualified. So it is not modifiable. It can't change.

`extern` doesn't matter, `extern` means that the object has external linkage - the definition of the object is somewhere else. Still, the object itself is not modifiable. Means, from the point of the C programming language, the value of the object will not change, nor by any function, nor ever.

Comment: The passage in this answer only allows us to conclude that the lvalue for `foo` used in the translation unit shown in the question is const-qualified. It does not give a reason that the object named `foo` is necessarily const-qualified throughout the program.

Answer (score 0):

> §6.7.3-6 states that the program may not assign to a const variable. It is not so clear to me that it implies that an external call cannot mutate this variable.

It should.  If data is `const` then the compiler is allowed to cache the data between calls.  Const means that the programmer is telling this data is not about to change (or be changed) not just to this compilation unit, but to all of them.  If other compilation unit defines this data as non-const, then all of them should declare it equal.  Anyway, it is clear, from what you have seen in the compiled assembly, that the compiler assumes the data is not to change, and so, the assumption is that the data will not change and so, the compiler can cache the values.

If you consider the data can be changed externally by other compilation units, you should turn your declaration into

```
const volatile int foo;
```

instead, and you should then observe that the compiler will not assume anymore the data has not changed and will not cache its value.

Answer (score -1):

The language definition says only that

> An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways unknown to the implementation or have other unknown side effects. Therefore any expression referring to such an object shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine, as described in 5.1.2.3.

*This* is the reason for `volatile` keyword. If `volatile` is not specified, C compiler can assume that every function call *will* conform to the standard and therefore will not change a non-`volatile`, `const`-qualified format.

Comment: One difficulty here is that the standard prohibits modifying a variable _defined_ as `const` and my variable here is only _declared_ as `const`.

Comment: @DavidMonniaux So don't lie to the compiler?

Comment: I'm writing the compiler, so I'm not lying to it.

Comment: @DavidMonniaux If you are declaring an `extern` variable as `const` in your code, but the actual definition lacks `const`, you most certainly are lying to the compiler.  You **told** the compiler that the variable is `const` when it's not.