# Why is void classified differently from other basic types?

Tags: c, types, enums, void

On [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type) they classify types as:

1. Void types
2. Basic types
3. Enumerated types
4. Derived types

I cannot find the reason why they have classified `void` as a fundamental type. It implies that there is a difference between **basic** types like `int`, `char`, etc., and the `void` type. On the basis of *whether they are storing values or not*, they clearly differ: conceptually, `void` type denotes objects that do not store any values, but **basic**-typed objects do store values.

I feel that every classification should have a single and well-defined basis. But here, I feel that there is no single basis.

In my opinion, instead they could have classified them on the basis of *whether is it derived or not*:

1. Basic types (includes `void` as well)
2. Derived types (types that are derived using the basic types. includes `enum` types as well)

Here, I classified `void` as **basic** type because it is one of the standard types defined in standard and doesn't depend on any other types. I classified `enum` types as derived types because I viewed that the `enum` types represent values of `int` type, therefore concluding that `enum` types are derived (implicitly) from `int` type.

What could be there basis of classification? Does my classification makes sense?

Comment: `void` is very different than every other type. It represents the lack of type, and even a lack of a value.  Of course it makes sense to group it separately.

Comment: _"What could be there basis ..."_ - I would guess the need to distinguish between them when describing the rules that governs them in the standard.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, did you mean "you *cannot* have arrays or structs with `void` elements"?  Because indeed you can't.

Comment: "*`void` type denotes objects that do not store any values*" -- this is a serious misunderstanding.  There are no objects that do not store values.  `void` is an *incomplete* type that conveys no characteristics of objects.  (Other incomplete types convey *some* characteristics).  `void` has some special-case semantics, but that's not relevant to type categorization.

Answer (score 3):

> It implies that there is a difference between basic types like int,
> char, etc., and the void type.

How `void` differs from other types:

- `void` is incomplete by definition.
- You can't declare a variable of type `void`
- You cant have a `void` struct or union member
- You can't have an array of `void` elements
- You can't do pointer arithmetic on `void` pointers
- You can't dereference void `pointers`

Did I miss something?

Imagine an empty space. You can have this place coordinates (pointer). But do you think that it can be classified the same as planets or stars?

Comment: Re “You can't declare a variable of type `void`”: [Yes, you can.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70948856/msvc-why-extern-void-x-is-illegal-use-of-type-void/70949127#70949127)

Comment: @EricPostpischil ? A very long answer but I do not see how I can declare void variable https://godbolt.org/z/Kc7cMvszT

Comment: That is a definition. As my answer states, the C standard does not preclude declaring (not defining) an identifier for a `void` object with external linkage.

Comment: @EricPostpischil can you provide an example of such a declaration? (and it usage in `sizeof` for example).

Comment: `extern void x;`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil IMO it is compiled only by GCC family compilers as they have void extensions (ie sizeof(void) == 1) and arithmetic on void pointers.

Comment: GCC’s extension to allow arithmetic on `void *` is not related to acceptance of `extern void x;`. My answer discusses why `extern void x;` is not prohibited by the C standard, and it explains that using information in the standard, not information related to pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

First, cppreference.com’s classifications are its own choice. They do come from the standard in some sense, because C 2018 6.2.5 14 defines the *basic types*:

> The type `char`, the signed and unsigned integer types, and the floating types are collectively called the *basic types*. The basic types are complete object types. Even if the implementation defines two or more basic types to have the same representation, they are nevertheless different types.

C 2018 6.2.5 16 defines the *enumerated types*:

> An *enumeration* comprises a set of named integer constant values. Each distinct enumeration constitutes a different *enumerated type*.

C 2018 6.2.5 20 defines the *derived types*:

> Any number of derived types can be constructed from the object and function types, as follows:…

and that leaves `void` out in the cold, on its own and not explicitly stated to be part of any class of types, in C 2018 6.2.5 19:

> The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that cannot be completed.

But the standard does not say these four categories are **the** way to classify types or that they are particularly notable. For example, cppreference.com could have said there are three categories, void, arithmetic, and derived, because *arithmetic types* include the basic types and enumerated types. Why did cppreference.com choose to split enumerated types off separately instead of adopting arithmetic types as the category? That is their own choice. It is an opinion, not a rule of the C standard.

That said, we can ask what makes `void` different from other types. Fundamentally, `void` is not intended to be used directly. Its primary purpose is to enable `void *` to serve as a generic pointer: A `void *` is a pointer to something, but we do not know what from the type alone. To use a `void *`, we do not dereference it to get a `void`. Instead, we convert it to a pointer to another type, such as a `char *` or a `double *` and use that.

The way the authors of the C standard made this work is to specify that the `void` type is *incomplete*. Incompleteness in C’s type system means we do not know something about a type. For example:

- `int a[]` is an array, but we do not know how many elements it has.
- `struct foo` is a structure, but we do not know what is in it.

With ordinary types, we can complete them. After `int a[];` declares an incomplete `a`, we can complete it with `int a[3];`. After `struct foo` declares an incomplete structure, we can complete it with `struct foo { int i; }`. However, `void` is specified to be a type that cannot be completed. After `extern void x;`, you cannot write `int x;` to say “That unknown thing is actually an `int`.” This makes it special because no other type has this rule.

So it is reasonable to put `void` in its own category. Nonetheless, it remains an opinion what categories to use, not a rule of the C standard.